# How can i make GET request with this kind of API's on Sim800

Tags: http, get, iot, at-command, sim800

I can do single line GET requests with sim800 but I couldn't understand to use this API.

```
   curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.collectapi.com/pray/all?data.city=istanbul' \
  --header 'authorization: apikey 3tXXXMYAPIKEYq9:1RxvCMYAPIKEYgAG' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json'
```

It shows me how to use it with curl but I can't understand how can I make this as single line on Sim800

Comment: You question has nothing to do with STM32, it is just generic use of hardware and its API question. Google "sim800 GET request", there are plenty of tutorials out there on how to establish a HTTP request.

Comment: Yes I already know how to make GET request with sim800 but i have never seen this format before. For example how can i contact that separate lines like --url --header etc.

Comment: What you shown is `curl` command running on linux for sending a GET request, it has nothing to do with SIM800. You need to study the application note of SIM800 or check out the tutorial (there are plenty of them) on what AT command you need to set the URL, what AT command to set the HTTP header, etc.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know this was what I had to learn. I will search, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
AT+HTTPINIT<\r><\r><\n>OK<\r><\n>
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1<\r><\r><\n>OK<\r><\n>
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://api.collectapi.com/pray/all?data.city=kahramanmaras"<\r><\r><\n>OK<\r><\n>
 AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","authorization: apikey 3tvAtuSxxxxxx4zDlq9:1RxvC4fQTxxxxxGbgAG"<\r><\r><\n>OK<\r><\n>
 AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"<\r><\r><\n>OK<\r><\n>
AT+HTTPACTION=0<\r><\r><\n>OK<\r><\n>
<\r><\n>
+HTTPACTION: 0,603,0<\r>
```

I'm doing something wrong but I don't understand :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the at+httpread command to find out what is the error is it looks like a custom error rather than a HTTP error